# Android screen video recording

Tags: android, opengl-es, video-encoding

How I should go about recording a video screen capture of an OpenGL application?

So far my plan of attack is to take individual screenshots then run it through a video encoder.

Does anyone here know of any sample code I can look at or has any suggestions of things I can look at?

I'm looking for the OpenGL app to capture in game footage and save it as video content.

Comment: You can record video of the application running on the emulator with DDMS, although I doubt that's what you're looking for. Maybe if you tell us your goal

Comment: DDMS allows video recording? How? I only know about still screen captures. I looked for the same to do screencasts, but the closes I found was this: http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/ and it doesn't run very smooth. So if you want to use it for creating a demonstration video of your app, it's not very useful, cause it's too slow regarding frame updates.

Answer (score 1):

As of Android 4.4, there is a screen recording feature accessible via adb.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord

> The screenrecord command is a shell utility for recording the display of devices running Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher. The utility records screen activity to an MPEG-4 file, which you can then download and use as part of a video presentation. This utility is useful for developers who want to create promotional or training videos without using a separate recording device.